# Using two different layouts for a GUI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gui

I am trying to design a GUI for two Android tablets. Both runs on Android 2.2. One is Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 and another one is China tablet. This China tablet is too big when compared with Samsung tab. I am trying to write two different xmls for a Single GUI based upon the tablet the respective xml file have to be loaded.

> I have tried xlarge and large attributes for the layout folder but both the tabs take there resources from large.
>
> And I also tried using layout-sw720dp and sw600dp both the tablets dint use this resource at all. Its just referring from normal layout folder.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 take layout from layout-xhdpi if this not there then it will look for large.

Comment: Adarwal thanks for helping me out this works fine. China tablet is not referring from layout-xhdpi but Galaxy does :) how does this works ? how does galaxy looks for xhdpi first ?

Comment: The problem is that particular model of Galaxy Tab, it reports the wrong screen bucket and DPI. Makes it a nightmare to design cross device UI's. Read more here: http://realmike.org/blog/2010/12/21/multiple-screen-sizes-with-processing-for-android/